# calloc does not work for large numbers

Tags: c, memory, size, allocation, calloc

In my program, `calloc()` does not work for more than 38 size, but with less than this number it works perfectly.  In this case, I want to allocate 128 of `int`, and release it afterwards.

What's up?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *x;
    x = malloc(512 / sizeof(int));
    a = x;
    int n = (512 / sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Address of x[%d] = %x\n", i, x );
        printf("Value of x[%d] = %d\n", i, *x );
        x++;
    }
    free(a);
    int *y = (int *)malloc(512 / sizeof(int));
    a = y;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Address of y[%d] = %x\n", i, y );
        printf("Value of y[%d] = %d\n", i, *y );
        y++;
        *y = i + 1;
    }
    free(a);
    int *z = (int *)calloc(38, sizeof(int));
    a = z;
    for (i = 0; i < 38; i++)
    {
        printf("Address of z[%d] = %x\n", i, z );
        printf("Value of z[%d] = %d\n", i, *z );
        z++;
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("Value of y[%d] = %d\n", i, *y );` `*y` is uninitialized.

Comment: if `n = 512 / sizeof(int)` then `malloc(512/sizeof(int))` is wrong, it has to be `malloc(512)`.

Comment: Please describe the error you get.  Also consider removing irrelevant code from your example.  My bet is that while doing so, the problem will already go away.

Comment: `calloc doesn't work` is not much to go on.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it's not a misunderstanding on your part or a simple bug--`calloc` must be broken. :-)

Comment: @user3386109: `sizeof(int)` is normally 4 (and `CHAR_BIT` is normally 8), even on 64-bit systems.  It is possible to have an ILP64 system (where `int`, `long` and pointers are 64-bit), but the de facto standard on Unix is LP64 (`long` and pointers are 64-bit), while it is LLP64 (`long long` and pointers are 64-bit) for Windows 64-bit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's nice, but it's still no excuse to write `n = 512 / sizeof(int)`, when the intent is simply `n = 128`. Quote, *"I want to allocate 128 of int"*

Comment: @user3386109: My concern was not that `512/sizeof(int)` is good; it isn't — it is bad because, as you say, it does not guarantee 128 `int` values.  My concern was your claim that `sizeof(int) == 8` on 64-bit systems (implicit in your assertion that there'd be only '64 entries on a 64-bit system').  I'm picking a nit in your comment, not disagreeing with the overall gist of the comment.  If you want 128 integers, allocate (at least) `malloc(128 * sizeof(int))` or `calloc(128, sizeof(int))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem, you don't initialize the values of `x` or `y` and still you try to print them, while the other problem, being the more important, is:

```
n = 512/sizeof(int)
```

and then you malloc

```
x = malloc(512/sizeof(int))
```

you should `malloc` this way

```
x = malloc(n*sizeof(int))
```

which yields

```
x = malloc(512)
```

but since you want to allocate `128 of int`, it is clearer to do

```
n = 128;
x = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

this is the fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *x;
    x = malloc (512);
    a = x;
    int n = (512/sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *x = i; /* intialize the value of x[i] */
        printf("Address of x[%d] = %p\n", i, x );
        printf("Value of x[%d] = %d\n", i, *x );
        x++;
    }
    free(a);

    int *y = malloc(512);
    a = y;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        *y = i+1; /* initialize the value of y[i] */
        printf("Address of y[%d] = %p\n", i, y );
        printf("Value of y[%d] = %d\n", i, *y );
        /* *y = i+1; move this before the printf */
        y++;
    }
    free(a);
    int *z = calloc(38, sizeof(int));
    a = z;
    for (i = 0; i < 38; i++)
    {
        printf("Address of z[%d] = %p\n", i, z );
        printf("Value of z[%d] = %d\n", i, *z );
        z++;
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

You must always check the result of `malloc` it returns `NULL` on failure. If it does return `NULL` and you don't check, you would dereference a `NULL` pointer, which is not a good idea.

The irony is that the only part of your code that was actually right, was the `calloc` part, except for not checking the returned value from it.